# How was the conditional probability obtained in this equation?

Tags: probability, bayesian

I'm reading about inverse problems and the Bayesian approach and I'm having troubles understanding how the following equations were obtained.

We consider the following equation initially.

$y=G(u)+\eta$

$y$ is a set of measured data. $G$ is a mathematical model and $u$ are the parameters of the model. The noise that is present in the observed data is given by $\eta$ (0 mean noise).

The authors then go on to describe the Bayesian approach and they say that the likelihood function, that is the probability of $y$ given $u$ is given by:

$\rho(y|u)=\rho(y-G(u))$

How did they derive this relation above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since $G$ is known, when $u$ is given so it is $G(u)$. So,

$$\begin{align}
  P(y = y_0|u = u_0) &= P(y = y_0|G(u) = G(u_0)) \\
                   &= P(G(u) + \eta = y_0 | G(u) = G(u_0)) \\
                   &= P(\eta = y_0 - G(u)| G(u) = G(u_0)) \\
                   &= P(\eta = y_0 - G(u_0)) 
  \end{align}$$

Setting ${\eta}_0 = y_0 - G(u_0)$ we get that $P(y = y_0 | u = u_0) = P(\eta = {\eta}_0)$ or in other words:
$$P(y|u) = P(\eta)$$

Substitute $\eta = y - G(u)$ by the first equation and you get the authors' claim.